# What are the current recommended best-practices for comments.php?

Tags: comments, customization, templates

I'm getting ready to submit a theme to the .Org repo and wanted to make sure that everything is in ordnung. One of the biggest holes left in my design is the comments template.

I've taken a look at comments.php in a few themes, Twenty Ten chief among them and have come away more confused than when I started. It seems as though (based upon tutorials from Otto, WP Engineer, etc.) the comments template has been simplified, yet when I look at the source to most themes' comments.php, they are still as convoluted as in the Christian-Montoya-derived days of old.

So help me out -- what's the best way to set up a comments template that will capture the state-of-the art functionality as of WP 3.0/3.1 and yet maintain code simplicity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really don’t need much.

### A headline with id=comments

```
<h2 id="comments"><?php comments_number(); ?></h2>
```

This will be the target for [`comments_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_link) in the article loop.

### Links for paginated comments.

Usually, I put these links into a function and call the function above and below the comments list:

```
class TTT_Template {
    function comment_pager()
    {
        if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) )
        {
            ?>
            <div class="comment-navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous">
                <?php
                previous_comments_link( 'Ältere Kommentare' );
                ?>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-next">
                <?php
                next_comments_link( 'Neuere Kommentare' );
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
```

### wp_list_comments()

You may use a custom callback function, but you don’t have to. For a theme on wp.org I’d use gravatars in the callback. And I wouldn’t namespace it with `my_`. ;)

```
<ol class="commentlist">
<?php
wp_list_comments(
    array (
        'type'     => 'comment'
    ,   'style'    => 'ul'
    ,   'callback' => 'my_comment_callback'
    )
);
?></ol>
```

As you can see, the `type` parameter allows you to separate normal comments from pings. See the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) for more information. If you build two separate lists, check  `get_option( 'default_ping_status' );` to avoid an empty list.

### comment_form();

You may use [the default](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) settings or add your own filters. I use a [custom class](https://gist.github.com/565997) to move the textarea to top and rearrange some minor other things.

```
if ( comments_open( get_the_ID() ) )
{
    locate_template( array ( '/php/class.TTT_Comment_Form.php' ), TRUE, TRUE );
    $ttt_comment_class = new TTT_Comment_Form();
    comment_form();
}
```

And that’s all.

### Complete code

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) { die ('Nö.'); }

if ( have_comments() )
{
    ?><h2 id="comments"><?php comments_number(); ?></h2>
    <?php
    TTT_Template::comment_pager();
    ?>
    <ol class="commentlist">
    <?php
    wp_list_comments(
array (
            'type'  => 'comment'
        ,   'style' => 'ul'
        ,   'callback' => 'my_comment_callback'
    )
    );
    ?></ol>
    <?php
    TTT_Template::comment_pager();
}

if ( comments_open( get_the_ID() ) )
{
    locate_template( array ( '/php/class.TTT_Comment_Form.php' ), TRUE, TRUE );
    $ttt_comment_class = new TTT_Comment_Form();
    comment_form();
}
```

Comment: Okay, awesome, we're getting really close here. 

Does your method not require the check for password-protected posts? AFAICT, Twenty Ten (and others) still check for this.

Comment: @ZaMoose I don’t call `comments_template();` on password protected posts to save resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Disqus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/)

Comment: Perhaps I should have specified -- code must be self-hosted. This is going into the Theme Repository on WordPress.org. Disqus is a nice system, but it doesn't fit the requirements.

Comment: Disqus was my goto for years but it is blocked in China and does things in the background you may not like.